# Parse 64-bit binary datetime

Tags: datetime, parsing, binary

I have been trying to parse for a long time, but I just can't get it. I tried a lot of types and converters, but it didn't give any effect. Also i googled everywhere i can.

Here is full block of data:
`3D 08 41 CF AC D9 59 64 44 44`

Where is

- `3D` - type of data (datetime of length),
- `08` - length of data and data (of datetime)
- `41 CF AC D9 59 64 44 44` = `8 October 2020 10:38:46 UTC`

---

All other data was Big-endian and this block, maybe, same.

The closest binary data were Apple Absolute and Ole automation (current data was encoded in DCode and сompared with my data), but nevertheless they were not. Back-end is old and written on Java, maybe this will be some kind of clue.

### Edit

Thanks to @GiacomoCatenazzi, business got off the ground. I think that start of time is 01.01.1970, but it is not unix epoch. And there is difference between mod by hour or by seconds (like seconds fracture, but without milliseconds).
The main problem I see at the moment is to find out datetime with or without seconds.
First byte `41` - may be a true value. And last 2 or 3 bytes is often equal.

#### Relative times to Zero

- `3C` - `3D C2 3F BF` -1m

Where `3C` - type of data (datetime of 4 bytes)

- `3D 08` - `41 CE E1 1F E0 00 00 00` -1s
- `3D 08` - `41 CE E1 1F E0 02 22 22` 1s
- `3D 08` - `41 CF AC EB BF A2 A2 A2` Current datetime (Oct 15 2020 02:59:15 GMT+0300)
- `3C` - `3D C2 3F C0` 0 - Center
- `3C` - `3D C2 3F C1` 1m
- `3C` - `3D C2 3F FC` 1 hour
- `3C` - `3D C2 45 60` 1 day
- `3C` - `3D C2 F3 C0` 1 month
- `3C` - `3D CA 44 E0` 1 Year
- `3C` - `3E 8A BF E0` 25 year (Dec 26 1994 03:00:00 GMT+0300)
- `3C` - `3F 59 D6 CC` Current date only (Oct 15 2020) (`26711820` - minutes since 01.01.1970)

Comment: Do you have more information on where/which program/protocol uses such format? could you try different values? e.g. `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`? In that case, you may find out how the bytes works. Else: could you try to encode e.g. 1.Jan.1970, 00:00 UTC? Else, could you try to have two dates (and values) e.g. distanced nearly one minute? To reverse engineering we need much more information (and test). Else you should describe better the source of your data

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, i added info what i'm find out. Obviously, things are pretty straightforward with the minutes. But seconds...
Program language is RAD.

Comment: Error by hours: maybe it is local time (so summer time). seconds: GPS uses second since origin, UNIX prefer "wall time", so it discard leap seconds (18 since GPS time). Repetitions on last digits: this seems a division. It is also possible that there are two fields. In any case I cannot help more: this would requires much more time (and tests). It doesn't remember me any known structure, but datetime are very diverse in different protocols